# Visual studio 2013 property window bug

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013 my property window will not let me edit the value of any controls color. Is there something I did wrong or is this a bug? Notice the orange box in the screenshot. This box is in every control in my application. I'm not able to edit the color with the color picker.

```
<Border CornerRadius="5, 5, 5, 5">
  <Border.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0"
                         StartPoint="0,0">
      <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColorKey}}"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#FF6D6D6D"
                    Offset=".5" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Border>
```

Background>

[image]

EDIT:

```
<Border CornerRadius="5, 5, 5, 5" Background="Black" >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The orange highlight on the Tab (Gradient) does not indicate that it is using a binding.  It indicates that you've selected the Gradient tab or that their is a gradient brush applied.  Click on the other tabs, and you'll see the highlight move.

Binding is indicated in the small box next to properties.

[image]